# Change labels of data inside of R Shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, rshiny

How do I change the labels of my "filtered_data" data frame when I am rendering the Data Table. The code to render the data is below.

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
  DT::datatable(filtered_data(), options = list(searching = TRUE,pageLength = 5,
                                                lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20), scrollX = T))
)
```

This seems easy but eludes me...

Comment: Do you mean to change the column names of `filtered_data()` ? Also it would be helpful if you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for Custom Column Names in https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

```
datatable(filtered_data(), colnames = c('Here', 'Are', 'Some', 'New', 'Names'))
```